# Is there a browser independet bookmarktool supporting tags, date and free comments?

Tags: bookmarks

I am looking for a tool, which helps me to organize my **personal** bookmarks.

I want to be able to assign **tags** and free **comments** to a bookmark.

I want to search my bookmarks by

- tags
- date of bookmarking
- pattern in title
- pattern in url

It would be nice to be web based to enable sharing my bookmarks between different machines.

But for it would be OK, if it works on a single machine as long as it has some import/export way to transfer the links to a new machine replacing the old.

As browsers I'm using Firefox and ChromePlus. It would be nice, if the solution works with both browsers.

With free comments, I mean additional remarks stored for a bookmark, which is not essential for searching.

Comment: This question is off topic, as it is not programming related. For software recommendations you should go to http://superuser.com

Comment: Sorry, not really a question for stack-overflow. Perhaps superuser.com? (sister site to SO)

Comment: meanwhile I found http://mozilla.gunnars.net/firefox_bookmarks_tutorial.html . Can you tell me about Firefox Extensions expanding Firefox's bookmark manager?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) for some time now, and I think that it supports everything you listed. You can synchronize bookmarks across several computers and there's a web interface for bookmark management.

They did switch to freemium model recently, but I think that all bookmark capabilities are still free.

Comment: I used xmark in the past. But stopped last the end of 2010. Didn't notice that they are back. http://blog.xmarks.com/?p=2007. Good to know. Xmarks solves the sync part and I just found that Firefox Bookmark manager fulfills most of my other requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can use Delicious. http://www.delicious.com/ extension.addon are available for both browsers.